# MS Access 2003 - Radio button : click one, unselects another

Tags: ms-access, vba, radio-button, ms-access-2003

So what VBA can i use to make sure that is radYes is clicked, radNo is unselected? Just a measure to make sure that if one is clicked then other cannot be

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Access, as in Classic VB, put the radio buttons in a Group Box.

Comment: Yep. The resulting object is called a frame, and you can check its value.